# AES Decryption (Excess Letters,Characters,Symbols/Missing Letters,Characters,Symbols)

Tags: java, encryption, aes

We are creating a system that encrypts and decrypts a .java file, specifically codes.
It is now 100% running, but we have a certain problem in the phase of decryption.
In our system, the encrypted file will change its file extension from .java to .aes.
Then, in the part of decrypting the .aes file to return to .java, it doesn't return to the EXACT FORM. There are symbols/letters/characters that are appearing.

Example: 
Original .java file: system.out.print
Encrypted: 4567jhgcvbhjkljh
Decrypted: system.ou"///nshujjprint

below : Code Snippet of the decryption portion

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    AES aes = null;
    String password = "timothyjamesorti";
    String toDecipher = "   //Decrypt Rounds 9 through 1\n" + 
    "for(int i = 9; i>0; i--){\n" +
    "   invShiftRows();\n" +
    "   subInvBytes();\n" +
    "   addRoundKey(i);\n" +
    "   invMixCols();\n" +
    "}\n" +
    "\n" +
    "//Decrypt a partial round 0\n" +
    "invShiftRows();\n" +
    "subInvBytes();\n" +
    "addRoundKey(0);\n" +
    "\n" +
    "mode = PLAIN; //Change the mode.\n" +
    "}\n" +
    "\n" +
    "}";

    String outputString = "";
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    int len = toDecipher.length();
    int spaces = 16 - (len % 16);
    if(spaces > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < spaces; i++){
            toDecipher += " ";
        }
    }
    System.out.println("toDecipherLength: " + toDecipher.length());

    while(toDecipher.length() >= 16){
        String candidate = toDecipher.substring(0, 16);
        toDecipher = toDecipher.substring(16, toDecipher.length());
        aes = new AES(password, candidate);
        strings.add(aes.ASE_Cipher_loop());
    }

    /**
     * 
     NmðìÀÁÝbÏÈ¼| ¦É¥Øsã7S:BÌ#g#asÈ GXD{ØIpÍà[g¥©jvÅ+72Vp¥Nè Ì2& ÞrK¸0qê0Ûî­QþAøÈgø¥îó.ÚÅ2Vüîýák>ëq*:(äÇf°®²KçS­³Jú+<Ëkã}&èf33äMï/eÏ)­¶Z¶~¬¡Yï`ývvL¥­¶:WÓ¯ÿ´ÁÿÅ4<péÊÑàV~å0vÓ]Âz
```

(d¬
         */

```
    String deciper = "NmðìÀÁÝbÏÈ¼| ¦É¥Øsã7S:BÌ#g#asÈ GXD{ØIpÍà[g¥©jvÅ+72Vp¥Nè Ì2& ÞrK¸0qê0Ûî­QþAøÈgø¥îó.ÚÅ2Vüîýák>ëq*:(äÇf°®²KçS­³Jú+<Ëkã}&èf33äMï/eÏ)­¶Z¶~¬¡Yï`ývvL¥­¶:WÓ¯ÿ´ÁÿÅ4<péÊÑàV~å0vÓ]Âz(d¬";
    strings = new ArrayList<>();
    len = deciper.length();
    spaces = 16 - (len % 16);
    if(spaces > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < spaces; i++){
            deciper += " ";
        }
    }
    outputString = "";
    System.out.println("toDecipherLength: " + deciper.length());
    String decrypted = "";
    while(deciper.length() >=16){
        String candidate = deciper.substring(0, 16);
        deciper = deciper.substring(16, deciper.length());
        aes = new AES(password, candidate);
        decrypted += aes.ASE_Decipher_loop();
    }

    /*for(String string : strings){
        aes = new AES(password, string);
        outputString += aes.ASE_Decipher_loop();
    }*/
    decrypted = decrypted.substring(0, decrypted.length() - spaces);
    System.out.println(decrypted);

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");  

    try  
    {  
        Date date = format.parse("2013-01-2013"); 
        System.out.println("date: " + date);
    }  

    catch(ParseException e)  
    {  
    e.printStackTrace();   
    }  
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using ECB, which is not secure.  You need to use CBC with a random unique IV.

Comment: Sir, what is ECB and CBC? Can you explain it further? Thanks.

Comment: Security is **hard**.  You are not capable of building secure code from basic primitives like AES.  You should use an existing high-level crypto library that handles all of these issues, like NaCl.  https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium

Comment: You can get started by reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation, but that is not enough to use AES securely.